# Star Wars - What is the "main port"?

Tags: star-wars

In a well-known scene in A New Hope, a rebel analyst describes the Death Star's weakness: "A small thermal exhaust port, right below the main port."

What is the "main port?"

[image: Rebel Briefing]

Comment: The main thermal exhaust port?

Comment: I have a vague memory of this being better explained in one of the early adaptations, but I can't find it in the earlier scripts, the novelization, the comic book adaptation, or the radio adaptation.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

That would be the Main Exhaust Port, noting that the weakness in the Death Star was an unshielded *secondary* port.

[image]

> <sub><sup>[Star Wars: Blueprints - The Ultimate Collection](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Blueprints:_The_Ultimate_Collection)</sup></sub>

...

> “I understand that it’s on the plans. What I’m saying is I don’t want
> you to build it. It doesn’t make any sense to put a heat exhaust port
> there. The main exhaust port is already done, and if there is a need
> for additional ones-which I don’t believe there is, at all - **there are
> better places to put them than right next to the main one.** We don’t
> need it in this sector, and certainly not there.” She pointed at the
> holo schematic of the polar trench.
>
> <sub><sup>[*Star Wars: Death Star*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Death_Star_(novel))</sup></sub>

Comment: Is she doubting the flawless design work of Galen Erso?!?!?

Comment: Is there also any detail about *what* is exhausted there? I mean the Death Star is meant to be operated in space, so I feel "hot air" is not really an answer there.

Comment: @kopaka possibly trash from the trash compactor?

Comment: @kopaka Actually, getting rid of excess heat is a major problem for real life space vessels, so it's not implausible.  Though hot *air* might not be correct.  In reality, this is typically done with large radiator arrays, not with just a hole.  Star Wars physics isn't exactly scientifically rigorous of course.

Comment: @kopaka - The Rogue One novelisation contains a considerable amount of information about what's exhausted. In short, a mixture of heat and radiation. Feel free to ask it as a proper question though, to get a proper answer :-)

Comment: Hot ether? Some of the early novels talked about "etheric rudders" that helped starfighters maneuver...

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Of course not! It's Legends, so she's doubting the flawless design work of Bevel Lemelisk.

Comment: @MiloP - Bevel Lemelisk was probably on Erso's team. You know how it is with these big projects.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman the Empire dealt with the heat issue by constructing an elaborate system of thermal exhaust ports. The rebels used a pencil to write “open this window if you get hot”.